# Mysql table structure for table with variable count of titles

Tags: php, mysql

I have size charts tables for products which I need to store in database. Now they are ordinary tables with titles like this: **Size**, **Bust**, **Hips** etc. The titles are not common for all tables. There are one mandatory title - **Size**. Others are changable and there are no static count for them. There could be 4 or 6 of them. I see two variants of storing these tables in DB. For starting point let's take that we have not tables but arrays like this:

```
[
    [
        'Size' => 'l'
        'Bust' => 1,
        'Hips' => 2
    ]
    [
        'Size' => 'm'
        'Bust' => 3,
        'Hips' => 4
    ]
]
```

First variant. Table structure: `id`, `data`. `data` stores serialized array.

Second variant. Table structure `id`, `table_id`, `size`, `bust`, `hips`, `waist` and so on. I included `waist` because as I said titles are not statid and are variable. One table could have it, another could not. I our case `waist` will be `null`.

So are there any other variants for table structure and which is the best?

Comment: Are the number of titles truly fixed, or could it increase/change in the future?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it could change in the future

Answer (score 1):

You should probably create three tables:

**Table 1 - options**

```
id int(11),
option_name varchar(255), // eg. size, waist, hips
PRIMARY_KEY(id)
```

**Table 2 - products**

```
id int(11),
name varchar(255),
...
PRIMARY_KEY(id)
```

**Table 3 - product_options**

```
product_id int(11),
option_id int(11),
option_value varchar(255) // eg. large, 36D, 4
```

This will give you maximum flexibility when you want to retrieve the data later. You would be able to retrieve all of the available options for given product with:

```
SELECT o.option_name, po.option_value FROM options o INNER JOIN product_options po ON o.id = po.option_id WHERE po.product_id = $productId
```